Do these polynomials with a complex kind of ‘Vieta jumping’ exist for all $k$?
Inspired by a recent question about sequences defined by $s_{n+1}=s_n^2-s_{n-1}^2$, I started wondering whether non trivial real or complex cycles of any length $k\geqslant3$ fixed by such a sequence exist.
If $k$ is a multiple of $3$, we have a "semi-trivial" cycle repeating $0,-1,1$, which will be disconsidered.
For $k=4$, there is no real cycle, but the (complex) roots of $64 x^4 + 16 x^2 + 16 x + 7$ form such a cycle, to wit: $$
\frac1{2 \sqrt{2}} + \frac i2 \sqrt{1 + \frac1{\sqrt{2}}} \Rightarrow 
\frac1{2 \sqrt{2}} - \frac i2 \sqrt{1 - \frac1{\sqrt{2}}} \Rightarrow 
\frac1{2 \sqrt{2}} + \frac i2 \sqrt{1 - \frac1{\sqrt{2}}} \Rightarrow 
\frac1{2 \sqrt{2}} - \frac i2 \sqrt{1 + \frac1{\sqrt{2}}}  $$
For $k=5$, as stated in a comment, there is a real and also a complex cycle (along with its conjugate). The complex one consists of $5$ of the $10$ complex roots of a certain degree $15$ polynomial with considerably big coefficients, while for the real one, I have found by running an algdep algorithm with high precision that the corresponding polynomial must have a degree bigger than $100$.
Likewise for $k=6$, there is a non trivial real and a complex cycle, along with its conjugate again, featuring the $6$ real roots and $6$ of the $12$ complex roots of one same (!) degree $18$ polynomial.
Bigger $k$'s go beyond Wolfram's standard computation time, but based on the numerical evidence [and intuition] so far, I would conjecture the following:

For $k\geqslant3$, there exists a non trivial fixed chain for the initial sequence. Moreover, there exists at least one polynomial with integer coefficients such that a certain subset of its (real and/or complex) roots, in a certain cyclic ordering, yields a fixed cycle for the sequence $s_{n+1}=s_n^2-s_{n-1}^2$.

(Note that those solutions must obviously be algebraic numbers, so it is natural to consider their minimal polynomials.) Any idea how to prove that?

Update 2: The following is a sketch on how to prove:

If $k>3$, then there is a "non-semi-trivial" complex $k$-cycle.
If $k>4$, then there is a "non-semi-trivial" real $k$-cycle.

We study the projective variety given by the polynomials $f_i=xx_{i+2}-x_{i+1}^2+x_i^2$, $0\le i\le k-1$, and indices taken modulo $k$, in projective space consisting of the points $[x_1:x_2:\cdots:x_k:x]$. The points at infinity are the $2^{k-1}$ points where $x=0$ and $x_i=\pm1$. In these points, the Jacobian matrix has rank $k$ provided that $\sum_ix_i\ne0$. This of course holds whenever $k$ is odd.
Furthermore, the Jacobian matrix has rank $k$ too in the point $[0:0:\cdots:0:1]$. Thus these are all points with multiplicity $1$. Therefore, if $k$ is odd, B'ezout's Theorem tells us that there are $2^k-2^{k-1}-1=2^{k-1}-1$ more complex points, counted with multiplicities. As this number is odd and complex points come in conjugate pairs, there must be non-trivial real points.
If $k$ is not divisible by $3$, there is no "semi-trivial" solution. This argument applies to divisors of $k$ too: Thus if $k$ has a prime divisor $p>3$, then there is a "non-semi-trivial" real $p$-cycle and therefore such a $k$-cycle.
So the only cases which are not covered are of the form $k=2^a3^b$. But there is a "non-semi-trivial" real $6$-cycle, so we are reduced to check the cases $k=2^a$ and $k=3^b$. There is a complex $4$-cycle, and an easy calculation with some polynomial systems solver like msolve reveals a real $8$-cycle. Similarly, there is a "non-semi-trivial" real $9$-cycle, and we are done.

Update 1: The approach sketched below is probably harder to complete as I expected initially. Even the existence of non-trivial complex solutions does not seem to be obvious. Here is another idea, maybe someone sees how to complete it: We need to study the variety given by the polynomials $f_i=x_{i+2}-x_{i+1}^2+x_i^2$, $0\le i\le k-1$, and indices taken modulo $k$. If there were no nonzero solution, then by Hilbert's Nullstellensatz, $x_0^r$ were a polynomial linear combination of the $f_i$'s for some sufficiently big $r$. Maybe there is a simple trick showing that this cannot hold for $k\ge3$. (And similarly, in order to exclude the "semi-trivial" solutions when $k$ is a multiple of $3$, one would need to show that $(x_0^3-x_0)^r$ is not in the ideal generated by the $f_i$'s.)

I'm pretty sure that the conjecture holds, and an approach might be the following: Let $s_0=x$ and $s_1=y$ be indeterminates. Then $F(x, y)=s_k-x$ and $G(x, y)=s_{k+1}-y$ describe algebraic curves, and we need to show that there are non-trivial complex points on the intersection of them.
If $F$ and $G$ have a common factor, then this holds of course. Thus assume that this is not the case.  By a simple induction, $F$ and $G$ have degrees $2^{k-1}$ and $2^k$, respectively. Thus, by Bézout's theorem, the number of intersection points of these two curves in the projective plane over $\mathbb C$, counted with multiplicities, is $2^{2k-1}$.
So in order to see that there are nontrivial points, we need to show that there are not "too many" points at infinity. How do we find the points at infinity? These are the points with projective coordinates $(u:v:0)$ where $F_h(u,v)=G_h(u,v)=0$, where $F_h$ and $G_h$ are the highest homogeneous components of $F$ and $G$. Fortunately, these components are easy to compute, they are $(x^2-y^2)^{2^{k-2}}$ and $(x^2-y^2)^{2^{k-1}}$.
From this information it shouldn't be hard to see that there are finite non-trivial complex points on the intersection of $F=0$ and $G=0$.
Note that the second question about the roots of integer polynomials is obvious once we know that there is a complex $k$-cycle: The resultants of $F(x,y)$ and $G(x,y)$ with respect to $x$ and $y$ yield  univariate polynomials for $x$ and $y$ over the integers, respectively. As $s_i$ is in the field generated by $x$ and $y$, all $s_i$'s are roots of integer polynomials.

Thank you! Yes, re your final remark, initially I wanted to formulate the conjecture directly in terms of the polynomials, but then I figured that they are a "natural" consequence of the existence of such cycles, so this wouldn't have captured the essential of the question. Now, from your arguments, it seems pretty clear that there are always roots in $\mathbb C$. I'd guess the existence of real roots is much trickier...

@Wolfgang Well, I believe that without counting multiplicities, there are $2^{k-1}$ finite complex solutions. As the non-real solutions come in pairs, there is an even number of real solutions. As there is the trivial solution $x=y=0$, there must be a nontrivial real solution too.

That looks appealing for odd $k$, but doesn't work for $k=4$ where there seem to be only 5 solutions in total. Or maybe it depends on what you call 'multiplicities' here? (not clear to me)

@Wolfgang Indeed, for $k=4,6,8$ (and probably larger odd $k$) the count is not as claimed. So one possibly really has to count with regard to multiplicities. In particular, one need to compute the multiplicities of the two points $(1:1:0)$ and $(1:-1:0)$ at infinity of the intersection of $F=0$ with $G=0$. Fulton's free copy of his book 'Algebraic Curves' at https://dept.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf describes in Section 3.3 how to do that. Haven't tried if it can be worked out here for general $k$.
